# how to make html <a target='_parent'> point to the same as javascript window.opener?

Tags: javascript, html, href, window.opener

In my project, I have a main page, where the user logs in and sees the main tables, as well as many additional pages, which open in different windows.

When the login timeout, the user should not be able to access any content. In the main page, I give a link to the login page again. In the sub-windows, I can't do that, because I don't want the login to be done in a sub-window.

In javascript, I can use window.opener to have access to the main window (since each sub-window is opened with window.open). How can I do that inside an html `a` tag?

```
if (!login_check($conn)) { // tests if the user is connected
    // exits with a message, if not connected anymore
    exit("<p>You don't have authorization to access this page. Please, <a href='index.php' target='_parent'>go back to main screen and login</a>.</p>");
}
```

The problem is: this code opens the login page on the sub-window, so `target='_parent'` does not act like I have thought. What is the proper way to achieve this, if any?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you assign `window.name` property of the original window some value (e.g. `"master"`) then you can target that window simply by `<a target="master">`.

Here is simple proof-of-concept in dataURI format: copy & paste to your location bar, Chrome/Firefox only; hard to simulate any other way here:

```
data:text/html,<script>window.name="master";</script>I am master. <button onclick="window.open('data:text/html,<a target=\'master\' href=\'data:text/plain,content for master from slave\'>Replace content of master</a>')">Open slave</button>
```

There is even quite amusing possibility to set masterʼs (openerʼs) `name` from within slave, but only if both share same origin:

```
<a onclick='if(window.opener)window.opener.name=this.target=Math.random()' href='whatever'>Open whatever in opener, if any</a>
```

[MDN: window.name](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/name)

Comment: Strange, I followed your first paragraph only, and it worked. But before that, I could open only one window for each php file, now I'm opening many of the same php file. Any idea why?

Answer (score 1):

You can't.

`target` only lets you navigate between frames in the current window/tab.

Only JavaScript has access to the opener. I haven't tested the following, but it should point you in the right direction.

```js
document.querySelector('.login-expired a').addEventListener('click', open_in_opener);

function open_in_opener(event) {
  window.opener.location = this.href;
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<p class="login-expired">You don't have authorization to access this page. Please, <a href='index.php'>go back to main screen and login</a>.</p>
```

Answer (score 1):

Target is for frames and iframes. You need to handle with javascript like this

```
 <a href="#" onclick="window.opener.location.href = 'index.php'; return false;">
```

Good luck